# JavaScript click event not working on div

Tags: javascript

I have two colored divs on which I want to put events on. I have selected them using getElementById and that worked fine - when I console.log the variable I get the right div.

However, the click event doesn't seem to fire at all. I basically just wanted to check if it works with console.log so that is what the function returns.

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <html>
   <head>
   <style>
  #red{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
   }

  #blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    </div>
      <div class="color picker">
        <h2>Pick a color!</h2>
          <div id="red"></div>
          <div id="blue"></div>
          <div id="green"></div>
    </div>          
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

And here the JavaScript

```
var redColor = document.getElementById('red');
var blueColor = document.getElementById('blue');


function loadEventListeners(){

  redColor.addEventListener('click', pickRed);

};


function pickRed(){

  console.log("You have selected red");
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: When does your scrip run in relation to HTML?

Comment: You may want to wrap your code in DOMContentLoaded so that the JavaScript waits for the elements to be drawn to the page before executing. document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded ', function(){ //configure here }); -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: Where is `loadEventListeners` called? How is the script included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loadEventListeners function is never being called. You can call it directly after or use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)

```js
function pickRed(){
  console.log("You have selected red");
}

function loadEventListeners(){
  document.getElementById('red').addEventListener('click', pickRed);
};

loadEventListeners();
```

```css
#red{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
  <html>
   <head>
</head>
<body>
    </div>
      <div class="color picker">
        <h2>Pick a color!</h2>
          <div id="red"></div>
          <div id="blue"></div>
          <div id="green"></div>
    </div>          
    </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: You know you can Ctrl+M or click the `<>` button and make the snippet on site?

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you haven't called `loadEventListeners`. Doing that should solve the problem.

Comment: @RubensMelo why is that comment on this answer and that comment is wrong.